# Is there a void return higher-order function?

Tags: arrays, swift, higher-order-functions

Consider the following case, we have an array of values that we need to use in a class, however we don't need an output from that array using higher-order functions .

for example lets say we have a function `func used(cells: [UITableViewCell.Type])` we need to register those cells in a `UITableView`
we can easily use `for-loop` but I'am trying to achieve this using higher order functions, since its faster writing .

**Full code example** :

```
func used(cells: [UITableViewCell.Type]){
        for cell in cells {
            self.register(cell)
        } // by foor loop
       _ = cells.map { self.register($0) } // using map 
    }
```

As you can see using `.map` will give me a return type of `[T]` and not declaring a variable name would throw me a compiler warning of

> Result of call to 'map' is unused

What i want is not having to write the `_ =` part .

Is there a higher-order function that I'am not aware with that actually used for this purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is such a function. It's called [forEach](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach).

The name is the same as in other functional languages, e.g. Javascript.

Comment: Great, the joke is i used it multiple times, xd my brain lagged after days of working  hours i feel ashamed i should delete the thread

Answer (score 0):

Lets clear up what are High-order functions first

Standard High-order functions in swift exists to manipulate a collection of data to modify it, so there is always a return type using the standard functions like

- Map
- FlatMap
- Reduce
- Filter

Those are always going to return whether it was `T` or `[T]`, its actually a mechanic of `throws` and `rethrows`  but that's another topic

What can you do is creating your own function extending the collection type you need for example an `array` the code would be something like this .

```
   extension Array {
    // T is the output type
    func voidlyMap<T>(_ transform: (Element) -> T)  {
        for item in self {
           _ = transform(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Using `transform(item)` will return the value when you type `$0` declaratively, so using this would be identical to `.map` simply with nothing to return, therefore no warnings from the compiler  just using it directly

**Usage :**

```
let foo = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"]
foo.voidlyMap{ print($0)} // prints foo1 foo2 foo3
```